# angularjs: FileUpload method with single parameter getting error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create an angular function to call a web api for uploading file. I get an error when I execute it. Below are the function and error message.

```
$scope.UploadFiles = function (id) {
    debugger;
    var fd = new FormData($('form')[1]);
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined,
            'cache': false,
            'processData': false,
        },
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        data:fd
    };
    $http.post('/api/Project/PostProjectFiles', id, config)
        .then(function (response) {
            alert('File Upload SUCCESS'+response.data);
        })
      .catch(function (response) {
          alert('File Upload FAILED: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
          console.log(response.data);
      })
```

Error message:

```
"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:63104/api/Project/PostProjectFiles'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Project' that matches the request."
```

My API accepts only one param

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostProjectFiles(int id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0 && id>0)
        {
            Project objProject = dbContext.Projects.Find(id);

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];

                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName.ToString();
                    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                    { 
                    var fileNameWithID = id.ToString() + "_A_" + fileName;
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + fileNameWithID);
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                    objProject.AFileID = fileNameWithID;
                    objProject.AFile = fileName;
                    }

                }
                else if (i == 1)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName.ToString();
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                    {
                        var fileNameWithID = id.ToString() + "_N_" + fileName;
                        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + fileNameWithID);
                        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                        objProject.NFileID = fileNameWithID;
                        objProject.NFile = fileName;
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {

                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName.ToString();
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                    {
                        var fileNameWithID = id.ToString() + "_Other_" + fileName;
                        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + fileNameWithID);
                        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                        objProject.OtherFileID = fileNameWithID;
                        objProject.OtherFile = fileName;
                    }
                }
                i++;

            }
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
        else
        {
            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Please also note that the action method is present in the controller and I am not sure why the error is popping up.

Config,

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
```

Comment: can you show more of the server API definition?  this is clearly a server issue, so the server code is much more useful than the calling code here.

Comment: done. please check

Comment: that's not exactly what I meant;  This issue is related to routing, so seeing how the routing and the class structure is set up is more important than the actual code related to the function itself....  The function isn't being called, so it doesn't really matter what it's contents are.

Comment: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

Comment: don't add code in comments; it can't be formatted to be readable.